# How to change style of the selected point in Google Charts?

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts to build a Line Graph and I need to change the style of the selected point.

The code below customizes the points individually when the graph loads, but I need to style the point after the user selects/clicks the point. I need to change the color, size and stroke-width of the selected point.

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable
        ([['X', 'Y', {'type': 'string', 'role': 'style'}],
          [1, 3, null],
          [2, 2.5, null],
          [3, 3, null],
          [4, 4, null],
          [5, 4, null],
          [6, 3, 'point { size: 18; shape-type: star; fill-color: #a52714; visible: false }'],
          [7, 2.5, null],
          [8, 3, null]
    ]);

    var options = {
      legend: 'none',
      hAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 9 },
      curveType: 'function',
      pointSize: 7,
      dataOpacity: 0.3
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

Comment: how you was able to resolve this issue? it was fixed or not.